# How do I find all documents (in a collection) in mongodb using the @Query annotation

Tags: mongodb, spring-annotations, spring-data-mongodb

The `@Query` annotation makes it possible to specify a MongoDB query for a particular method. An example might be `@Query("{ 'firstname' : ?0 }")`. But what should the parameter to `@Query` be if I just want to find all documents without specifying a "where" clause? The code below illustrates what I'm trying to achieve but perhaps the question is simply: what is the JSON/BSON query to fetch all documents?

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface QuoteRepository {

    public QuoteProvider findByName(String name);

    public List<QuoteProvider> findAllQuoteProviders();

}

@Repository
public interface MongoQuoteRepository extends QuoteRepository, MongoRepository<QuoteProvider, String> {

    @Query("findAll") // What should this be?
    @Override
    public List<QuoteProvider> findAllQuoteProviders();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test at the moment, but since it as far as I know has the same query syntax as `find()`, this should work to get all entries without a condition;

```
@Query("{}")
```